# Filter list with Union Type

Tags: f#

I am new in F# and fp. I try to filter a list with the discriminated union type as parameter.
In my example, I want everyone who has type A. How could I solve this, or is that a bad approach?

```
type U =
    | A of AA
    | B of BB
    | C

and AA = {
    Id: string
}

and BB = {
    Id: string
}


let list = [ A { Id = "0" }; B { Id = "1" }; C; A { Id = "2"}]
let filter (union: U) = list |> List.filter(fun x -> x = union)

let resultOne = filter A //Error
let resultTow = filter C //Ok
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To do this sort of thing, the usual approach is to create a helper function and then use it as parameter for `List.filter`:

```
let isA u = match u with
    | A _ -> true
    | _ -> false

let resultOne = list |> List.filter isA
```

Or you could put the helper function inline, without giving it a name:

```
let resultOne = list |> List.filter (fun u -> match u with A _ -> true | _ -> false)
```

Or, if you're really into terseness, you can use the `function` syntax (which is sugar for `fun x -> match x with`):

```
let resultOne = list |> List.filter (function A _ -> true | _ -> false)
```

Comment: Ok, but i need for every case in the discriminated union a helper function. 
Isn't that very awkward?

Comment: Why would it be awkward? You need a computation to be done, you make a function for it. That's how programming generally works.

Comment: It's cumbersome because I need a function for every case. It would be easier if I could just check the case identifier. But that's not possible as it seems.